# extract data from three table with one table act as intermediate

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Please help me in this situation.

The output that i want should be display in below example of table.

click [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByLJ3uyXYTw3eFg5NEdfRlA0WEU/edit)

- For first cell, i need to display male which already done HIV filter and he is less than 19 years old.

  - Same goes to next cell, i need to display female that already done HIV filter and she is less than 19 years old and same goes to next row with different age group.
  - Gender and age group are in table DONOR_MST with column GENDER and DOB
  - Total patients that already HIV filtered is in table BAT_TESDET with column RES_HIV
  - However, this two table did not have any match Primary Key.

Then i do got one table name PRE_SCREEN which contains match column in DONOR_MST and BAT_TESDET

Below are the PK of each table :

- Table DONOR_MST with column DONOR_ID
- Table BAT_TESDET with column DISP_ID and BARCODE
- Table PRE_SCREEN with column DONOR_ID and BARCODE

I did try to use INNER JOIN but it didnt work. Below is my code

```
     SELECT 
     (CASE c.GENDER WHEN '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MALE,
     (CASE c.GENDER WHEN '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FEMALE,
     (CASE  WHEN (datediff(YEAR, c.DOB, getdate()))  < 19 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
     (CASE  WHEN (datediff(YEAR, c.DOB, getdate()))  BETWEEN 20 AND 24 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
     (CASE  WHEN (datediff(YEAR, c.DOB, getdate()))  BETWEEN 25 AND 29 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
     (CASE  WHEN (datediff(YEAR, c.DOB, getdate()))  BETWEEN 30 AND 34 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
     (CASE  WHEN (datediff(YEAR, c.DOB, getdate()))  BETWEEN 35 AND 39 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
     (CASE  WHEN (datediff(YEAR, c.DOB, getdate()))  BETWEEN 40 AND 44 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
     (CASE  WHEN (datediff(YEAR, c.DOB, getdate()))  BETWEEN 45 AND 49 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
     (CASE  WHEN (datediff(YEAR, c.DOB, getdate()))  BETWEEN 50 AND 54 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
     (CASE  WHEN (datediff(YEAR, c.DOB, getdate()))  > 55 THEN 1  ELSE 0 END ) 

    FROM  dbo.DONOR_MST c
    INNER JOIN dbo.PRE_SCREEN b
            ON c.DONOR_ID LIKE b.DONOR_ID
            INNER JOIN BAT_TESDET a
            ON b.BARCODE = a.BARCODE 
    WHERE 
    b.IS_ELIGIBLE = '1'
        AND b.SCR_DATE >= @STARTDATE
        AND b.SCR_DATE <= @ENDDATE
```

My question:

How i can link the three tables

Comment: did you try to INNER JOIN?

Comment: @Bulat, yes i did try the INNER JOIN but it didnt work.

Comment: Can you please add the query you tried to the question

Comment: @Bulat already add the query :)

Comment: why do you use LIKE in join statement? Also what exactly does not work, do you get an error message or not getting results you expect?

Comment: Im not getting result as expected. The output displayed the total of donors not total of donor that already HIV filtered. LIKE i change with '='

Comment: I think the question is not clear. Your tables are joint fine. It seems that you want to filter results based on RES_HIV field. Did you try to add condition to WHERE clause?

Comment: Consider creating SQL Fiddle example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @Bulat thanks..it works when i add more condition to WHERE clause =). Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposition of query in order to get those information:

```
SELECT D.DOB
,SUM(CASE
WHEN D.GENDER = 'MALE' THEN 1
ELSE 0
END) AS [MALE]
,SUM(CASE
WHEN D.GENDER = 'FEMALE' THEN 1
ELSE 0
END) AS [FEMALE]
,COUNT(*) AS [TOTAL]
FROM DONOR_MST D
INNER JOIN PRE_SCREEN P ON P.DONOR_ID = D.DONOR_ID
INNER JOIN BAT_TESDET B ON B.BARCODE = P.BARCODE
GROUP BY D.DOB
```

Hope this will help you.